# Trying to make a generated column in my postgres database using these attributes from my rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a model ServiceAgreement with :starts_at(Datetime), :ends_at(Datetime), and :service_interval(integer that corresponds to an enum)

```
{"weekly"=>0, "every_month"=>1, "biannually"=>2, "annually"=>3}
```

I need this virtual column to be an array of the proposed service dates based on the distance between starts_at and ends_at. ex. a two-year agreement with a "biannually" service interval should have 4 dates: 6 months, 12 months, 18 months, and 24 months from the start.

I can do it in ruby, but I'm having a hard time with the SQL for it.

Side note: How would I even write the add_column line in my migration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My 2 cents: You should create a new table for ServiceIntervals and associate it to the ServiceAgreement. e.g. `rails g model ServiceInterval interval_date:date service_agreement:references` then when a ServiceAgreement is created or updated you simply populate the values of this table with the data you calculate "in ruby".

Comment: If I can't find a solution by the end of the day, that might be the way to go; thanks for the idea! I wanted to try to keep it in the model because that's how it was explained to me.